# While loop is filling my 2D array with too many values

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

In short, my 2D array is being iterated through and filled with values. However, when outputting these values to console, it becomes clear that for some reason, the loop is iterating through too many times.

I can't seem to find anything on stack overflow pertaining to this problem. I don't really see a way to do this efficiently without using these loops.

Note: Pretty new to both C++ and Stack Overflow, if I have failed to provide any information deemed helpful, let me know and I will follow up.

```
void loadNames(string names[], int size, ifstream &inFile, double scores[10][5]) {
    string name;
    int grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5;
    int i = 0;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    while (inFile >> name >> grade1 >> grade2 >> grade3 >> grade4 >> grade5) {
        names[i] = name;
        i++;
        int colNames[5] = { grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5 };
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                scores[k][j] = colNames[j];
                cout << setw(5) << scores[k][j] << " " << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is that the array gets 5 values per line, and 10 rows of those values. However, output shows many times that number.

Here's the data

```
Johnson 85 83 77 91 76
Aniston 80 90 95 93 48
Cooper 78 82 22 90 73
Gupta 92 83 30 69 87
Blair 23 45 96 38 59
Clark 60 85 45 39 67
Kennedy 77 31 52 74 83
Bronson 93 94 89 77 97
Sunny 79 85 28 93 82
Smith 85 72 49 75 63
```

Comment: You have two variables named `i`, which is generally a recipe for disaster. It's not clear at first glance if that's your issue though.

Comment: @Frank updated with new variables, same issue. I believe the for loops i is self contained so it shouldn't matter

Comment: For each iteration, you are getting 5 values per line and 10 rows. It will repeat for the number of lines you have in `inFile`. May be you know there are only 10 lines in the file and you don't need the outer `for` loop?

Comment: @Wander3r compiler doesn't like the nonspecified row number

Comment: What I meant is whether you would need the for loop iterating over `k`. `scores[i][j] = colNames[j];` isn't enough?

Comment: @Wander3r it was originally an i loop but frank above me thought that the i after names may be interfering. Regardless, the loops variables are self contained to i or k shouldn't matter.

Comment: `int colNames[5] = { grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5 };
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                scores[i][j] = colNames[j];
                cout << setw(5) << scores[i][j] << " " << endl;
            }`

Comment: @Wander3r That throws a memory error 
```
Exception thrown at 0x01227BFE in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.
```

Comment: That means that the number of lines in the file is more than `10`. Better use a `vector` for store and push_back the values.